# How do I update my HTML when i make changes is CSS?

Tags: css

I have been working a little with HTML and it seems like HTML would remember my previous CSS code even after I make changes and update it. Right now I have commented out the custom stylesheet and it is still pulling colours from that! I am working with Django and here is my code:

```
{% extends 'accounts/main.html' %} 
{% load static %}
{% block content %}

<br>

<head>
    <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    {% comment %} <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">  {% endcomment %}
    {% comment %} <link rel="stylesheet" href="{%static "/css/Vstylesheet.css"%}"> {% endcomment %}
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{%static "/css/materialize.css"%}"  media="screen,projection"/>    
    <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
</head>

<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s3">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-content Vteal white-text">
          <span class="card-title">Balance</span>
          <h3 class="center-align flow-text ">{{balance}}</h3>
        </div>
      </div>    
    </div>
```

.
.
.

It shows up like this:[image]

CSS:

```
.Vteal{
   background-color: #1E252B; 
}

.Vblack{
    background-color: #13171A;
}

.Vgrey{
    background-color: #1E252B;
}

body{
    background-color: #13171A;
}

.cardVtitle{
    font-size: 40;
    font-weight: bold;

}
```

What do I do?

Comment: Maybe it's a cache problem. Try to disable cache.

Comment: No, this makes no sense, HTML does not have any such kind of “memory.” (Browser caching of the stylesheet itself is a thing of course, but that is different from what you are describing here.) We don’t know what kind of templating system this is supposed to be, maybe it has a cache for the generated HTML itself, or something like that. Either way, start by _verifying_ that the stylesheet you _think_ was not embedded, actually isn’t, by inspecting the whole thing with your browser dev tools.

Comment: Yep caching problem, thanks. I never knew that Google would cache this kind of thing as well, I thought it only did thumbnails and stuff! Anyways, thank you!

Comment: how do I mark this as an answer?? or can that not be done with comments??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Chrome Developer Tools open you can hold down the 'Reload this page' button and choose 'Empty cache and hard reload'. See attached screen.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was helped by the wonderful people who commented. I disabled the cache and it works now! Thank you. The way to disable cache is - When you're in Google Chrome, click on View, then select Developer, then Developer Tools. Alternatively, you can right-click on a page in Chrome, then click Inspect. Click on the Network tab, then check the box to Disable cache. That check about is at the top of the developer toolbar!